# SQL Index Identity Column Sort Order

Tags: sql-server, indexing, primary-key

I have a transaction table:

```
|rowID|value1|value2|...|
|11111|12    |34    |...|
|11112|23    |123   |...|
|11113|99    |53    |...|
...
```

`RowID` is the Identity and increments by 1. Indexing is also no problem. Lots of new values get inserted, updates happen and sometimes some rows may get deleted.

But now I have a second table:

```
|rowID|flag1|flag2|...|
|11113|0    |1    |...|
|11111|1    |1    |...|
|11112|0    |1    |...|
...
```

It is a user operation, which inserts rows from the transaction table into this second table. `RowID` corresponds to `RowID` from the transaction table.

The insert to the second table are not sorted by the `RowID`. A higher `RowID` may be inserted earlier, than a lower `RowID`.

What is the best indexing strategy for such a table?

- Is it wise to define `RowID` in the second table as primary key, resulting in a clustered index? Which, I think, is not ideal because the `RowID`'s are not sorted.
- Is it better to have no primary key, but a suitable non-clustered index?

I wonder if there are some general advise for such a table (second table)?

Comment: You should (almost) always have a primary key on your tables. There are a very few times where a heap is the right approach. Also, if you don't want RowID to be the clustered index there is no rule that says a primary key must be the clustered index. It is just the default when creating a primary key. You can specify it to be nonclustered and add a different clustered index if the design and the data warrants it.

Answer (score 0):

Tables are not ordered dataset. The fact `RowID` isnt order on the second table doesnt matter at the moment of define PK/index.

You should make `RowID` the `PK` for `Table2` The moment the index is created a `B-TREE` is also created and the data is stored there for fastest access.